# Boostrap 3, toggle collapse wont stay closed on page load

Tags: html, css

Im using the the data-toggle="collapse" in boostrap 3 but on page load my hidden div content doesn't stay closed. I have searched many solutions, none of which has worked. Below is my code, apologies for the novices coding but i'm self employed and haven't had time to be fluent in html as yet.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/ground/grnd1.jpg" alt="...">
  <div class="caption">

    <p style=" color: dimgray;">text here,text here,text here,text here,text here,</p>
    <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#foundations" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#foundations" style="padding:2%;">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>

      <div class="container" >
                    <div class="collaspe" id="foundations" data-toggle="false">
                    <br><br>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <h1 style=" color: dimgray; font-weight:300; margin-top:5%;">Pad Foundations</h1>
                <br><br>
                    <img src="img/ground/grnd2.jpg" alt="..." style="width:100%;">
                     <p style=" color: dimgray;">text here, text here, text here, text here, </p><br><br>

                     <h1 style=" color: dimgray; font-weight:300; margin-top:5%;">Jack Pad Foundations</h1>
                     <img src="img/ground/grnd5.jpg" alt="..."  style="width:100%;">
                     <p style=" color: dimgray;">text here,text here,text   here,text here,</p><br><h2 style="font-weight: 300">Need advice?<a    href="contact_us.html">Contact us</a></h2><br><br>                   
  </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled "collapse" classname for div with id "foundations".

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/ground/grnd1.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">

                    <p style=" color: dimgray;">text here,text here,text here,text here,text here,</p>
                    <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#foundations" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#foundations" style="padding:2%;">Continue Reading &raquo;</a>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="collapse" id="foundations" data-toggle="false">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <h1 style=" color: dimgray; font-weight:300; margin-top:5%;">Pad Foundations</h1>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <img src="img/ground/grnd2.jpg" alt="..." style="width:100%;">
                            <p style=" color: dimgray;">text here, text here, text here, text here, </p>
                            <br>
                            <br>

                            <h1 style=" color: dimgray; font-weight:300; margin-top:5%;">Jack Pad Foundations</h1>
                            <img src="img/ground/grnd5.jpg" alt="..." style="width:100%;">
                            <p style=" color: dimgray;">text here,text here,text here,text here,</p>
                            <br>
                            <h2 style="font-weight: 300">Need advice?<a    href="contact_us.html">Contact us</a></h2>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lol that sums up my day, thank you greatly Chitrang it works!! I have been trying to sort this out for 3 hours lol.